# Escaping special characters in URL for C# WebMethod

Tags: c#, web-services, error-handling, special-characters

I have a C# WebService with several methods that have differing quantities of parameters.  Within each of the web methods I have been able to establish error logic to check for expected values, however, in cases where the URL that is being sent to the server with special characters in the URL, I am unable to properly handle the exceptions.

```
public class ClientGroupMgmt : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public string readConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ClientDB"].ConnectionString;

    //List of Special characters
    public string[] BadChars = { ">", "<", "&", "@", "#" };

    [WebMethod]
    public List<ClientGroupInfo> getAllClientGroupInfo()
    [WebMethod]
    public List<ClientGroupInfo> getClientGroupsbyClientID(string clientid)
    [WebMethod]
    public List<ClientGroupInfo> addClientGroup(string clientid, string clientGroupName, string prodIssueID, string intMailDistro)
if(BadChars.Any(s=>clientid.Contains(s)))
            {
                //Error
                Error = "Special characters are not allowed.";
                throw new Exception(Error);
            }
```

I think that I should capture the URL value in the parent WebService class and Encode/Decode it to strip out the special characters, but I have not found any examples that are of any help.  When I debug this in Visual Studio and use the WSDL window to provide parameters, the code functions correctly and provides the proper responses to the special characters, however, when it is deployed to the server, the special character of # is ignored and treated as an expected end of URL character.  My other thought was to possibly monitor the number of parameters and error on less than quantity expected, however, that has not shown up in any of my research.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.
Regards,
Bill

Comment: You could try passing your string through `System.Uri.EscapeDataString` first. That should take care of such characters.

Comment: [(Please) Stop Using Unsafe Characters in URLs](https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/)